# Orange Pi 5 power supply boot-up issue

Tags: power-supply, pcb, current, boost, startup-issues

I am a newbie using the Orange Pi 5 board, or any kind like this.

I have a boot-up issue.  When I connect it to the power supply, only the red light is on (on the board). I do not see anything when I connect the display by HDMI-HDMI or HDMI-TypeC.

I am not sure if my new board is functioning or not. The problem is, the requirement says this needs 5V-4A, but for some reason my new power supply shipping will come later, so I use 5V-2A for test currently, and I am not sure 2A will be able to boot up the board, or at least I can see the startup screen.

I will get my 5V-4A power next week, but the reason why I want to try with 2A now is because I want to know if my board is functioning or not, otherwise, I need to return to the retail store and replace a new one.

Can anyone tell if 5V-2A can boot the board, or if my board is just not functioning?

Is there any other way to work around? Maybe can I connect this with an iPad power adapter? The iPad adapter specification says it outputs 5V-3A or 9V-2.22A, isn't it about the PD standard? I read the Orange Pi 5 user manual, and it says that the board has no PD support, so can I still use the iPad adapter to power it, or will it damage the board?

Comment: Hello at EE.SE. Site standards include spaces between magnitudes and units, and, at least there, finicky capitalization. For greetings and thanks, please see [Expected Behaviour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: (I think it's *boot* (start up) rather than `boost`.) ("It might, perhaps, sometimes, work with a RPi4 5V 3A PSU, as long as you don't have anything else connected when booting." (reddit))

Comment: Welcome! Hard to tell for sure since there are many things which needs to function before you have an image on HDMI. Measure the 5 V rail with your oscilloscope. If it dips, that's probably the issue.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting _"Boot is short for bootstrap[1][2] or bootstrap load and derives from the phrase to pull oneself up by one's bootstraps."_